# MPAndroidChart: PieChart onValueSelected is not called

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have a problem with the PieChart. I am updating the Chart every time the Activity is called and I'm doing this with:

```
private void setupPieChart() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mChart.setLayoutParams(params);

    mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

    /**
     * Hide the Description and the Legend.
     */
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    /**
     * Hole in the middle.
     */
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHoleRadius(50);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(55);

    mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
    mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            switch (e.getXIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    startLearning(e.getXIndex());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    startLearning(e.getXIndex());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    startLearning(e.getXIndex());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    startLearning(e.getXIndex());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    startLearning(e.getXIndex());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
            System.out.println("onNothingSelected");
        }
    });

    addDataForPieChart();
}
```

And I'm adding the data with:

```
private void addDataForPieChart() {
    /**
     * Data of the Chart.
     */
    float[] value = mCurrentLearnSet.getCountFromLevel();
    String[] names = {"First Level", "Second Level", "Third Level", "Forth Level", "Fifth Level"};

    /**
     * Create needed Entries.
     */
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (value[i] != 0) {
            entries.add(new Entry(value[i], i));
            strings.add(names[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create pie data set.
     */
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Your Progress");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);

    /**
     * Setup Colors.
     */
    dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS);

    /**
     * Instantiate pie data object.
     */
    PieData data = new PieData(strings, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(13f);
    data.setValueTextColor(R.color.primary_text);

    /**
     * Set the Data to the PieChart.
     */
    mChart.setData(data);

    /**
     * Undo all highlights.
     */
    mChart.highlightValues(null);

    /**
     * Update pie chart.
     */
    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

My problem is following:

There is a different amount of slices in the chart every time its created. From time to time the `OnChartValueSelectedListener()` doesn't work correctly. The slices are displayed correctly, but the method `onValueSelected()` is never called so i can't click them. There is no Error or highlighting though. Just `onNothingSelected()` is called.

Please advice, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the missing index of the entries in follwing code segment. Since I removed the if statement, the code works correctly again.

```
/**
 * Create needed Entries.
 */
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (value[i] != 0) { // <--
        entries.add(new Entry(value[i], i));
        strings.add(names[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score -1):

I think you have set mchart.data.setHighLightEnabled(false), try setting this to true at that time onValueSelected() will be called